# ADX project column with a new column containing white space

Tags: azure, azure-data-explorer, adx

Is it possible to project a ADX column with a new column name that has whitespace?

For instance,
`Covid19_map2`
`| project "My Area Info" = AreaInfo`

Here is the ADX sample cluster query
https://dataexplorer.azure.com/clusters/help/databases/Samples?query=H4sIAAAAAAAAA3POL8tMMbSMz00sMOKqUSgoys9KTS5RUPKtVHAsSk1U8MxLy1dSsAVzQGwA7I7HADAAAAA=

Answer (score 1, accepted):

please see: [Identifier quoting](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-explorer/kusto/query/schema-entities/entity-names#identifier-quoting)

for example:

```
Covid19_map2
| project ["My Area Info"] = AreaInfo
```